# Dialog popup works once

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I am using jquery Dialog to open a modal to edit a form which is on a partial view.

When I first click the edit link to open the modal the form appears as it should, correctly styled etc. and I am able to save the changes I have made. This then closes the modal.

Now when I click the edit link on the next record the form loads not in the modal but replaces my current view.

The div that should be loaded is

```
<div id="popupAction" style="display: none;" ></div>
```

I have the following to control the modal:

```
$(function () {
    $("#popupAction").dialog({
        width: 600,
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true
    });

    $('a.AddActionFunction').on("click", function () {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#popupAction').load(url, function () {
            $('#popupAction').dialog('open');
        });
        return false;
    });
    $('a.EditActionFunction').on("click", function () {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#popupAction').load(url, function () {
            $('#popupAction').dialog('open');
        });
        return false;
    });
});

function closePopupAction() {
    $("#popupAction").dialog("close");
}
```

I am using this with asp.net mvc. In my partial view I have the following:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditSetting", "CustomerSupportAction", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "current-actions-setting-list", OnSuccess = "closePopupAction" }))
```

Comment: Is this a caching issue? Does adding `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });` help?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Getting js errors now - object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'

Comment: Have you included jQuery UI and if you have, does it contain the `dialog` component?

Comment: Yes, the dialog appears the first time I click the link, just not after that when the link is clicked again.

Comment: Perhaps the page or part of the page with the links on is refreshing/reloading when you close the dialog, and the jQuery isn't being called again to rebind the click events that prompt the dialog?

Comment: Have just figured it out. I needed to split the click events up and add them to their appropriate views. The add event was fine on the main view, but the edit event needed added to the partial view.